# How do I get Trello Clone to work?

Tags: trello, list

I am trying to find an easy way to duplicate check lists on cards (like many others).

I have downloaded [Trello Clone](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/igdohpdnohikeonpipombhdepnmbigkl) several times. I cannot get it to show up in the widget area at all. I have tried the show/hide trick and the F5? but nothing works.

If I can't get Clone to work is there a way to attach a checklist created in Excel?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/igdohpdnohikeonpipombhdepnmbigkl

Comment: As this is a self hosted application questions about it are off topic for Web Applications.

Comment: FWIW, the team just launched board copying. For more info, there's a card for it here https://trello.com/card/copy-board-v1/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1265 and a blog post here http://blog.trello.com/you-can-copy-boards-now-finally/

Answer (score 3):

Trello Clone is not made or maintained by [Fog Creek Software](http://fogcreek.com) or the Trello team. We are currently at work on allow you to copy/template cards/boards/lists/checklists. [Here is the feature request](https://trello.com/card/copy-clone-template-boards-lists-cards-and-checklists/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/961).

Trello Clone is [hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/oo7ph/Trello-Clone/issues), and so you might get traction with it in the meantime by interacting with that user community.